# Jmeter Webdriver sendKeys() won't set a value to a text box with a mask

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am trying to fill up a form with "JMeter webdriver" (???) using the `sendKeys()` function.

I am doing fine in each of the other textboxes (finding it by id, and then setting the value using `sendKeys()`) , but there is a textbox with a JavaScript mask attached to it (it's a zip code so the mask is 99999-9999).

I can verify that the values are being inserted by the `sendKeys` function but the mask just reset it back to empty.

This does not happen when I try to fill in the textbox using the FireFox Selenium IDE.

Any ideas how to pass this?

Comment: Can you provide link to your page and WebDriver Sampler code?

Comment: Hi Bob,
Unfortunately - i can't (protected behind a username + pass..)
Is there something else i can provide which can help?

Comment: What version of Firefox is installed on your computer and what version of Selenium are you using?  Also, are you using Grid or a local Firefox?

Comment: Hi,
My FireFox version is 25.0.1 and the Selenium IDE version is 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not use "Selenium IDE" and instead, use "[Selenium Builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/)".

Comment: Hi,there isn't any problem with the Selenium IDE.
The problem is when i use `sendKeys()` on this textbox - it clears the value.

Comment: Thats ok.  That is a known issue.  The release notes of Selenium reveal they have been fiddling with sendKeys lately.  Just make sure you are using the latest version of Selenium that matches your web browser and you should be ok.  I found a bug with Chrome 30 on Linux through Grid but I am not surprised you get a similar error in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with a masked input for a phone number. ( ) - .

I was able to get selenium to put the cursor in the right place by clearing the textbox before sending keys

```
var txtPhone = _pageHelper.WaitForElementToExist(_phone);
txtPhone.Clear();
txtPhone.SendKeys(phone);
```